# Changing a column type from varchar to CLOB with JPA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3, jta

I'm trying to change the data type of a column using the JPA annotation:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="CLOB")
private String description;
```

Whenever this entity is persisted, a VARCHAR value is attempted to be stored, which is not long enough. I couldn't find any documentation on the @Column annotation specific to CLOB except one that defined a column = "CLOB NOT NULL". I want NULL values to be allowed. Is "CLOB" not the correct column definition here?

I'm using EclipseLink to persist to a JavaDB database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `@Lob` annotation on the field. 
API doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html

Comment: Thanks Korgen. Guess I didn't know what to Google.